# Powershell Workflows, continue after reboot

Tags: powershell

PowerShell Workflows are new to me, and have done a lot of reading on the subject, but still have some question unanswered.

1. I guess that variables are not retained after the reboot of the workflow computer? So you will need to recreate your variables after the reboot?
2. Do you place the complete script in the workflow, or just the part that instigates the reboot and the tasks that follows the reboot?

I am building a script that promotes a member server to a domain controller, installs some required software. After the reboot I need to add some privileges on the WMIMGMT, which needs to be done after the server has been promoted to DC, hence why a reboot is required.

Answer (score 0):

I does not sound that it is intended for the workflow to do this out of the box.
Rather you would run the scrip remotely with commands that listen for computer restart and if it is up again.